# How does rotate and shift instructions in assembly 8086 affect overflow flag

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, emu8086

After trying many exemples i still can't find the rule to detect when the overflow flag is set in the case of rotate and shift instructions

For exemple here :

```
MOV AX,6EH
MOV CL,2
SHL AL,CL
```

The overflow flag is set to one when the sign bit doesn't change in the last rotation

Comment: Actually the rule is the reverse. It's set to one if the sign **does** change (that's when you have an overflow). Note that the instruction set reference says: _"The OF flag is affected only for 1-bit shifts; otherwise, it is undefined."_ So don't count on it being generally true.

Comment: @Jester exactly in my case it's one when the sign didn't change so it's kinda confusing, i've found on the internet that it's only considered in one bit shifts but my textbooks exemples don't follow this rule

Comment: Real life cpus seem to use either the first or the last shift. emu8086 may decide to leave the flag unchanged. As to what your textbook uses, we can't tell.

Comment: What textbook, and what does it actually say?  Do they have examples of code the rely on OF being set by a shift or rotate with count other than 1?  If so, that's a bug, because it's not guaranteed, and as Jester commented on the linked duplicate, AMD CPUs in practice do it differently from Intel CPUs for that case where the x86 documentation doesn't specify the result.

Comment: Your example seems to match the intel behavior: just use the first shift to determine the overflow.